# How to specify ENTER button functionality in Selenium WebDriver code using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, dropdown, enter

For practice sake, I'm writing test cases for irctc website, there I need to enter **from** station place and then respective stations with that code will be displayed as bootstrap dropdown and now i have to select one among them and click enter. Unfortunately there is no enter/submit button for from and **to** text field, please help me to continue with this test case

Here is my code

````
IWebElement Fromstn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='divMain']/div/app-main-page/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-jp-input/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/i"));
                 Thread.Sleep(2000);
                  Fromstn.SendKeys("MAQ");
                  Fromstn.Click();
 ```**OR**
````

Actions builder = new Actions(driver); Actions hover = builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='origin']"))); hover.Build().Perform(); Thread.Sleep(2000); hover.SendKeys("MAQ"); hover.Click();

Comment: Have you tried any code? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, If I give sendKeys or Click on the WebElement, It throws an exception that element not interactable

Comment: Please share the xpath you have tried

Comment: I tried with Actions aswel,  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                Actions hover = builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='origin']")));
                hover.Build().Perform();
                Thread.Sleep(2000); hover.SendKeys("MAQ"); hover.Click();  both are not working..... how to enter text here and how to choose the respective station

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**from** input try the below css :

```
p-autocomplete#origin input
```

**To** input try the below css :

```
p-autocomplete#destination input
```

**Code  :**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p-autocomplete#origin input")).SendKeys("MAQ");
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p-autocomplete#destination input")).SendKeys("some to station");
```

and if you wanna do Keyboard enter then probably use it with `sendkeys():`

something like this :

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p-autocomplete#origin input")).SendKeys("MAQ" + Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: Is it possible to autochoose the dropdown value, as soon as we enter  first 3 letters ....like If I type MAQ, dropdown shows MANGALURU CNTL-MAQ and have to select it....instead of doing it manually like Keys.return

Comment: keys.return should not be manual right ? how are you using this ? yes we may have to hover over to auto populated options and click on it.

Comment: ya, it should not be manual....now I am selecting auto populated options and clicking it manually

Comment: No, no you should not do it like that, are you login into application ?

Comment: I mean can you tell me  your automation steps.. like launch the irctc.com and then..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234123/discussion-between-aishwarya-mohan-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='From']/..//input")).SendKeys("MAQ");
//Add a wait time for the drop down value to load
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Actions hover = builder.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//ul[@id='pr_id_1_list']/li"))).Click().Perform();
```

Comment: are you adding wait time after sendKeys()?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. For debugging see the Fromstn object in the quick watch and see if it has returned the correct element. for debugging you can also see the element is still in the form by 'inspect element' and do a find with the Xpath given when you are on the breakpoint.

```
IWebElement Fromstn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='divMain']/div/app-main-page/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/app-jp-input/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/i"));
Thread.Sleep(2000); //you can also try by increasing the value for testing say 10 seconds
Fromstn.Clear();
Fromstn.SendKeys("MAQ");
Fromstn.Click();
```